# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de normalizar dos tablas de personal con diferente informacion?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos

Esto es a manera de ejemplo de la situación que tengo.
Hay 2 tablas de personal o usuarios:

Alumnos:
|idAlumno | nombre | fNacimiento | id_curso | columna 5 | columna 6 |

Profesores
|idProfesor | nombre |fNacimiento | salario | columna 8 | columna 9 |

El problema me nace cuando quiero crear una tabla solicitudes en la cual tanto profesores como alumnos puedan crear solicitudes, que hacer en estos casos, ¿crear una columna idAlumno y otra idProfesor?, ¿crear una tercera tabla con la información de los usuarios?( cabe mencionar que solo me interesa para los solicitudes el nombre de usuarios y la fecha de nacimiento considerando que los tipos de usuarios almacenan información diferente).

Ej: Solicitudes(con ambas ids):
|idSolicitud| tituloSolicitud| textoSolicitud| idAlumno(?) | idProfesor (?)|

Finalmente considerar que no es un caso apartado, posteriormente podría crear la tabla reclamos la cual tendría la misma situación.

Se me ocurren algunas ideas de como resolverlo, pero me interesaría que me puedan ayudar a saber la forma "correcta" de resolverlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo ideal sería crear una tabla de usuarios y dos tablas específicas que hagan referencia al usuario.

```
Usuarios: |idUsuario | nombre | fNacimiento | tipo (alumno/profesor) | columna x |

Alumnos: |idUsuario | id_curso | columna 5 | columna 6 |

Profesores |idUsuario | salario | columna 8 | columna 9 |
```

Comment: Entiendo la idea pero mi pregunta es la siguiente, en la tabla "usuarios" no podrías establecer una  FK hacia las otras tablas debido a que el campo "id_usuario" estaría apuntando hacia 2 tablas, ¿esta bien eso para la normalización de base de datos?

Comment: Al contrario, la llave primaria es la de la tabla usuarios y las otras dos tablas tienen a id_usuario como llave primaria y llave foranea que apunta a la tabla Usuarios. Es lo que se conoce como relación 1-1